# How do I make the response object visible in specific events?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm fairly new to nodeJS and I'm trying to enjoy myself by making a fully working login page.

*(And it works ! .. Well, kindof ..)*

I want the user to be redirected to another page with his data returned from the database after I press submit and eventually I found this thing while researching, which I don't think is a function but an event of some sort.

`req.on("end", (req, res) => {}`

The thing is however that the req and res objects are not visible inside there from the parent function.

So here's my question. What is that thing, and how can I make it so that those two objects will be visible inside that "thing" ?

`function something(req,res){
   console.log(res) // [Object]
   req.on("end",(req,res)=>{console.log(res); //undefined}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res` and `req` are Objects that consist of many properties.  The easiest way to format them would be to use  `console.log(JSON.stringify(res,null,2))`.

JSON.stringify(obj) will pretty-print the object and the `,null,2` adds 2 spaces and nothing else between the lines (to make it more readable).

Comment: Yes they are huge objects, and that's a propriety'ish thingy that looks to me like an event. I'm sorry If my question wasn't clear,I asked how do I make them visible again inside them ( sounds wierd but I need acess to it  ) , more specifically inside that callback function. For some reasons, in this case the req, and res objects are undefined inside that callback. And thank you for you'r awnser

Comment: I don't think you have enough code posted to really answer that.  It depends on how you have your server setup.  The HTTP server should be calling this function and passing in the req and res objects.  If it isn't, then your issue is outside of the code that you pasted.  There are *many* examples of starter HTTP servers on the web that might also help... otherwise, would you paste all of the relevant code?